# Understanding and solving K-Way merge sort

Tags: c#, java, algorithm, data-structures

I want to:

1. count the number of comparisons needed by k-Way merge sort to sort random permutation of numbers from 0 to N-1.
2. to count the number of data moves needed by K-Way merge sort to sort random permutation of numbers from 0 to N-1.

I understand how 2-way merge sort works correctly, and understand the code very well. My problem now is I don't know how to start. How do I convert the 2-way merge sort into K-Way so that I can solve the above problems?

I have searched the web but can't find any tutorial to explain "k-Way merge sort" very well.

I need good explanation what to do so that I can take it from there and do it myself.

Like I said I understand the 2-Way, so how do I move to the K-Way merge sort?  How do I implement the K-way?

### Edit

I read some post http://bchalk.com/work/view/k_way_merge_sort
that BinaryHeap must be used to implement k-Way merge. Is that so or there are other ways?

How do I divide my list into K? Is there a special way of doing it?

Comment: Binary heap is not required for a k-way merge. All you need is a way to quickly find the smallest in a list of k items, remove that item, and put another item into the list. The binary heap is often used because it's simple to implement and quite efficient for small lists. But you could use a skip list or any of a handful of other heap implementations, or some other priority queue implementation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When `k > 2`, the leading elements from each of the input streams are typically kept in a minheap structure.  This makes it easy to find to the mininum of the the n-values, to pop that value off the heap, and insert a replacement value from the corresponding input stream.

A heap does `O(lg2 k)` comparisons for each insertion, so the total work for a k-way merge of n items is `n * lg2(k)`.

Eventhough you asked about C# and Java, you can learn how to do it by looking at the Python standard library code for a k-way merge:  http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/heapq.py#l323

To answer your other question, there is no special way to divide your list into K groups.  Just take the first N/k elements in the first array, the next N/k elements into the next, etc.  Sort each array and then merge them using heaps as mentioned above.

Comment: No problem.  Good luck with your merging :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could always think of a k-way merge as a series of 2-way merges, that is, do a 2-way merge with the result of the first and second, and the third: `Merge(Merge(L1, L2), L3)` and so on. Even faster would be to split it twice: `Merge(Merge(L1, L2), Merge(L3, L4))`. As you can see, for a k-way sort, you would then need some sort of loop (recursion).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have edited my post a little bit. Can you help me?  thanks